# What chainring can replace Shimano SG-X 10S 34-F?

Tags: chainring, replacement

It seems my smaller chainring Shimano SG-X 10S 34-F (a Tiagra chainset of 2019 or so) in worn out, but I cannot find exactly the same one in stores.

Are there any modern parts that can be used as a replacement?

For example,

- Shimano Ultegra FC-6750
- Shimano 105 FC-5703 10-speed
  Seem to have the same 5 fixing points, but will they fit?